# How to do unit testing

Tags: unit-testing

I have a method `CreateTask(UserId)`.

For this method, is it enough to check `UserId` against `null` or empty and an invalid value?

Or should I check whether `Task` is created for a specific `UserId`?

And should I also check number of tasks created and their date and time?

Comment: Only you can tell, depending on what `CreateTask()` does and your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's enough information here to answer this.  But ti address some of your points:

> For this method, Is that enough to check UserId null or empty and invalid Id ?

The method itself can internally do that, but that's not part of testing.  That's just a method at runtime doing some error checking.  This is often referred to as "defensive programming."

> Or Should I check whether Task is created for the specif UserId.?

This is where it gets cloudy.  And this is where you would want to step back for a moment and look at the bigger picture.  Make sure you're not tightly coupling your unit tests with your implementation logic.  The tests should validate the business logic, unaware of the implementation.

It's *highly likely* that "creating a task" isn't business logic, but rather simply an implementation detail.  What you should be testing is that when Step A is performed, Result B is observed.  How the system goes about producing Result B is essentially what's being tested, but not directly or explicitly.

A big reason for keeping your unit tests high-level like this is because if the implementation details change then you don't want to have to change your tests with them.  That drastically reduces the value of those tests because it not only adds more work to any change but it eliminates the tests as the validation point of those change, since the tests themselves *also* change.  The tests should be fairly simple and static, acting as a set of rules used to validate the code.  If the tests are complex and often changing, they lose that level of confidence needed to validate the code.

You don't have to test every method.  You should test every observable business action that the system performs.  Methods which perform those actions get tested as a result of this.  Methods which don't perform those actions are then questionable as to whether or not you need them in the first place.  A code coverage tool is great for determining this.

For example, let's say you have `MethodA()` which doesn't get used by any of the tests.  No test calls it directly, because it's just an implementation detail and the tests don't need to know about it.  (In this case it might even make sense for the method to be private or in some other way obscured from the external calling code.)  This leaves you with two options:

1. The tests are incomplete, because `MethodA()` is needed by a business process which isn't being tested.  Add tests for that business process.
2. The tests are complete, and `MethodA()` isn't actually needed by the system.  Remove it.

If your tests blindly test every method regardless of the bigger picture of the business logic, you'd never be able to determine when something isn't needed by the system.  And deprecating code which is no longer needed is a *huge* part of keeping a simple and maintainable codebase.

Answer (score 0):

1) Keep your methods short and simple, so unit testing will be easy (btw. one of reasons that [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) encourages good design)

2) Check all boundary conditions (invalid input, trivial input etc.) (btw. one of ways to make [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) easy)

3) Check all possible scenarios to achieve high coverage (all possible execution flows through your method with simplest input to achieve this) (btw. one of reasons that [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) works)

4) Check few (maybe one) typical scenarios with real data that demonstrates typical usage of the method

And as you've probably noticed - consider using [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) so you won't have to worry about the issue of "testing an existing method" :)